# Publish to an Azure Event Hub with output bindings and use partition keys

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm publishing an object to an Azure Event Hub using output bindings like so.

```
[FunctionName("IntegrationFunction")]
[return: EventHub("%Transactions:EVH:Transactions:Hub%", Connection = "Transactions:EVH:Transactions")]
public Transaction Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(
        "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic%",
        "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:AnalyticsTopicSubscription%",
        Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
    string mySbMsg,
    ILogger log)
{
    var retailTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetailTransaction>(
        mySbMsg,
        JsonSerialisationUtils.SerialiserSettings);
    
    try
    {
        var transaction = retailTransaction.ToDto();
        log.LogInformation($"Transaction {transaction.TransactionNumber} processed.");
        return transaction;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.LogError(e, "Error mapping transaction.");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is there any way to publish it to a specific partition e.g. `transaction.StoreCode`?

Comment: Are you using the in-proc or isolated model?

Comment: In-process model

Comment: @Bhav Have you tried the example given for IAsyncCollector https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example

Comment: The answer below is correct with respect to using partition keys.  Note this is different than "to a specific partition" as you've stated in the question.   That requires setting a partition Id when sending, which requires you bind to the EventHubProducerClient.   The same sample linked below demonstrates doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the partition key value while publishing the events to EventHub using **`IAsyncCollector<EventData>`**. Refer the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=python-v2,in-process,nodejs-v4,functionsv2,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example) and [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28245#issuecomment-450965490) for more details.

- I am using the below code to set the partition key.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace _78148689
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("IntegrationFunction")]
        public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "serviceBusConnection")]string mySbMsg,
            [EventHub("test-hub", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]IAsyncCollector<EventData> outputEvents, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

            var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mySbMsg));

            await outputEvents.AddAsync(eventData, "demo-key");
        }
    }
}
```

**.csproj**-

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>_78148689</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I am able to publish the event.

[image]

[image]